# Using String.replace()  to replace slashes ie "\" 

Tags: java, string

I have a string like `C:\Users\temp\index.html` and want to replace `"\"` with `"\\"`. I have tried the following:

```
 str= str.replace("\", "\\");
```

.. but Eclipse keeps suggesting that I add arguments to the replace method.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the slash characters:

```
str = str.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your `\`. Use the `\` character to escape. The `\` is necessary to escape both `\` and `"`.

```
str.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="C:\Users\temp\index.html";
str = str.replace("\\", "\\\\");
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
str = str.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

As "\"  nullifies the effect of symbols which has special meaning in the language.